# tokenize according space and punctuation, punctuation kept

Tags: python, string, tokenize

I'm looking for a solution to tokenize or split according spaces or punctuation. Only the punctuation must be kept in the result. It will be using to recognize language (python, java, html, c...)

The input `string` could be:

```
class Foldermanagement():
def __init__(self):
    self.today = invoicemng.gettoday()
    ...
```

the output I'm expecting is a list/tokenized as described below:

```
['class', 'Foldermanagement', '(', ')', ':', 'def', '_', '_', 'init', ... ,'self', '.', 'today', '=', ...]
```

Any solution is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: In most programming languages, an underscore "_" is treated as an alphabetic character. You may not want to treat it as punctuation.

Comment: @DYZ I will keep that in mind, thank you for the comment. I will modify the code below accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here's what you are looking for:

```
import string, re, itertools
text = """
class Foldermanagement():
def __init__(self):
    self.today = invoicemng.gettoday()
       """
separators = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
separators_re = "|".join(re.escape(x) for x in separators)
tokens = zip(re.split(separators_re, text), re.findall(separators_re, text))
flattened = itertools.chain.from_iterable(tokens)
cleaned = [x for x in flattened if x and not x.isspace()]
# ['class', 'Foldermanagement', '(', ')', ':', 'def', '_', '_',
#  'init', '_', '_', '(', 'self', ')', ':', 'self', '.', 'today', '=', 
#  'invoicemng', '.', 'gettoday', '(', ')']
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you.
I really need to dive in the `re` package.